# Assets link to wrong release after Capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, passenger, capistrano3

So I am new with Capistrano and attempting to deploy my application with Capistrano.

Done a lot of Googling, really hard to figure out, all the docs I find, apply for older version of Capistrano and they seem to break compatibility with every other version.

But I stumbled upon a problem I can't seem to figure out by myself.

After Capistrano deploy, app assets link to wrong release folder and App just returns Missing template error.

```
App 30962 stderr: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template layouts/main_page with {:locale=>[:ru], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
App 30962 stderr:   * "/var/fruby/releases/20140213082235/app/views"
App 30962 stderr:   * "/var/fruby/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/views"
App 30962 stderr: ):
```

And indeed, the folder he is trying to access does not exist because the current release folder links to other release

```
current -> /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546
```

Notice how assets try accessing *20140213082235* and in reality, current release folder is *20140213100546*. And if it helps, it seems that *20140213082235* stays always the same folder he tries to access over and over again, no matter how many times I run deploy.

Hell this release doesn't even exist in releases folder. There is just one single release (I cleaned up before).

For sake of argument, I deleted shared/bin, releases folder, and current symlink before this particular deploy.

Here is my Capistrano deploy.rb

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
lock '3.1.0'

application_name = 'fruby'

set :use_sudo, true
set :application, application_name
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:someuser/someapp.git'

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app
set :deploy_to, "/var/#{application_name}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :rails_env, 'production'

set :scm, :git
set :format, :pretty
set :log_level, :debug

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp public}

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 2

namespace :deploy do

  task :fix_assets_permission do
    on roles(:web), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute "chown -R root:root /var/#{application_name}/shared/tmp/cache/;"
      execute "chmod 777 -R /var/#{application_name}/shared/tmp/cache/;"
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:web), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end


end

after 'deploy:compile_assets', 'deploy:fix_assets_permission'
```

and here is debug information Capistrano writes during deploy.

```
 INFO [8b5cf3f8] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/fruby/ on somedomain.com
DEBUG [8b5cf3f8] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/fruby/
 INFO [8b5cf3f8] Finished in 0.851 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/fruby/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
 INFO Uploading /tmp/fruby/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
 INFO [54bd7f1a] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/fruby/git-ssh.sh on somedomain.com
DEBUG [54bd7f1a] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/fruby/git-ssh.sh
 INFO [54bd7f1a] Finished in 0.102 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [5f2c9b73] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:someuser/someapp.git on somedomain.com
DEBUG [5f2c9b73] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/fruby/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:someuser/someapp.git )
DEBUG [5f2c9b73]    13a3d2301d5e62bdb9af52a0798907ch47d43356    HEAD
DEBUG [5f2c9b73]    13a3d2301d5e62bdb9af52a0798907ch47d43356    refs/heads/master
DEBUG [5f2c9b73] Finished in 1.853 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [0703251f] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/fruby/shared /var/fruby/releases on somedomain.com
DEBUG [0703251f] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/fruby/shared /var/fruby/releases
DEBUG [0703251f]    mkdir: created directory `/var/fruby/releases'
 INFO [0703251f] Finished in 0.104 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [12be6fbc] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/fruby/shared/log /var/fruby/shared/tmp /var/fruby/shared/public on somedomain.com
DEBUG [12be6fbc] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/fruby/shared/log /var/fruby/shared/tmp /var/fruby/shared/public
 INFO [12be6fbc] Finished in 0.104 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [b985d99b] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /var/fruby/repo/HEAD ] on somedomain.com
DEBUG [b985d99b] Command: [ -f /var/fruby/repo/HEAD ]
DEBUG [b985d99b] Finished in 0.100 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO The repository mirror is at /var/fruby/repo
DEBUG [353f5ba0] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/fruby/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/fruby/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on somedomain.com
DEBUG [353f5ba0] Command: if test ! -d /var/fruby/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/fruby/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [353f5ba0] Finished in 0.100 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [559df4f8] Running /usr/bin/env cd /var/fruby/repo && git rev-parse --short HEAD on somedomain.com
DEBUG [559df4f8] Command: cd /var/fruby/repo && git rev-parse --short HEAD
DEBUG [559df4f8]    13a3d23
DEBUG [559df4f8] Finished in 0.103 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [1c6ade67] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update on somedomain.com
DEBUG [1c6ade67] Command: cd /var/fruby/repo && /usr/bin/env git remote update
DEBUG [1c6ade67]    Fetching origin
 INFO [1c6ade67] Finished in 1.995 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [114fb8b6] Running /usr/bin/env cd /var/fruby/repo && git rev-parse --short HEAD on somedomain.com
DEBUG [114fb8b6] Command: cd /var/fruby/repo && git rev-parse --short HEAD
DEBUG [114fb8b6]    13a3d23
DEBUG [114fb8b6] Finished in 0.103 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [4cead9f2] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/fruby/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/fruby/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on somedomain.com
DEBUG [4cead9f2] Command: if test ! -d /var/fruby/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/fruby/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [4cead9f2] Finished in 0.100 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [dcb034dc] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546 on somedomain.com
DEBUG [dcb034dc] Command: cd /var/fruby/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/fruby/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546 )
 INFO [dcb034dc] Finished in 0.104 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [e5ae8a9d] Running /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -C /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546 on somedomain.com
DEBUG [e5ae8a9d] Command: cd /var/fruby/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/fruby/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -C /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546 )
 INFO [e5ae8a9d] Finished in 1.267 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [031a127d] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546 /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546 /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546 on somedomain.com
DEBUG [031a127d] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546 /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546 /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546
 INFO [031a127d] Finished in 0.103 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [2869942a] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/log ] on somedomain.com
DEBUG [2869942a] Command: [ -L /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/log ]
DEBUG [2869942a] Finished in 0.100 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [d8054077] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/log ] on somedomain.com
DEBUG [d8054077] Command: [ -d /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/log ]
DEBUG [d8054077] Finished in 0.099 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 INFO [8ee1aa40] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/fruby/shared/log /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/log on somedomain.com
DEBUG [8ee1aa40] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/fruby/shared/log /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/log
 INFO [8ee1aa40] Finished in 0.103 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [1c8e2ddf] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/tmp ] on somedomain.com
DEBUG [1c8e2ddf] Command: [ -L /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/tmp ]
DEBUG [1c8e2ddf] Finished in 0.099 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [29409e68] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/tmp ] on somedomain.com
DEBUG [29409e68] Command: [ -d /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/tmp ]
DEBUG [29409e68] Finished in 0.099 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 INFO [a0581377] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/fruby/shared/tmp /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/tmp on somedomain.com
DEBUG [a0581377] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/fruby/shared/tmp /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/tmp
 INFO [a0581377] Finished in 0.102 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [9b010c55] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/public ] on somedomain.com
DEBUG [9b010c55] Command: [ -L /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/public ]
DEBUG [9b010c55] Finished in 0.099 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [04e2b790] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/public ] on somedomain.com
DEBUG [04e2b790] Command: [ -d /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/public ]
DEBUG [04e2b790] Finished in 0.105 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [869e3d51] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/public on somedomain.com
DEBUG [869e3d51] Command: /usr/bin/env rm -rf /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/public
 INFO [869e3d51] Finished in 0.130 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [60aeb659] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/fruby/shared/public /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/public on somedomain.com
DEBUG [60aeb659] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/fruby/shared/public /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/public
 INFO [60aeb659] Finished in 0.102 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [c487b30d] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/fruby/releases/20140213100546'" 1>&2; false; fi on somedomain.com
DEBUG [c487b30d] Command: if test ! -d /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/fruby/releases/20140213100546'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [c487b30d] Finished in 0.100 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [7e4baf5b] Running /usr/bin/env bundle install --binstubs /var/fruby/shared/bin --path /var/fruby/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet on somedomain.com
DEBUG [7e4baf5b] Command: cd /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546 && /usr/bin/env bundle install --binstubs /var/fruby/shared/bin --path /var/fruby/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
 INFO [7e4baf5b] Finished in 1.808 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [cac16d29] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/fruby/releases/20140213100546'" 1>&2; false; fi on somedomain.com
DEBUG [cac16d29] Command: if test ! -d /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/fruby/releases/20140213100546'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [cac16d29] Finished in 0.096 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [c4c22728] Running bundle exec rake assets:precompile on somedomain.com
DEBUG [c4c22728] Command: cd /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546 && ( RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [c4c22728]    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /var/fruby/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
DEBUG [c4c22728]    [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
DEBUG [c4c22728]    ** [Raven] Raven 0.7.1 ready to catch errors
DEBUG [c4c22728]    [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
DEBUG [c4c22728]    ** [Raven] Raven 0.7.1 ready to catch errors
DEBUG [c4c22728]    [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
DEBUG [c4c22728]    ** [Raven] Raven 0.7.1 ready to catch errors
DEBUG [c4c22728]    [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
 INFO [c4c22728] Finished in 213.492 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [13f65310] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/fruby/releases/20140213100546'" 1>&2; false; fi on somedomain.com
DEBUG [13f65310] Command: if test ! -d /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/fruby/releases/20140213100546'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [13f65310] Finished in 0.714 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [2372bebc] Running /usr/bin/env cp /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/public/assets/manifest* /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/assets_manifest_backup on somedomain.com
DEBUG [2372bebc] Command: cd /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546 && /usr/bin/env cp /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/public/assets/manifest* /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546/assets_manifest_backup
 INFO [2372bebc] Finished in 0.106 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [fd9ff012] Running /usr/bin/env chown -R root:root /var/fruby/shared/tmp/cache/; on somedomain.com
DEBUG [fd9ff012] Command: chown -R root:root /var/fruby/shared/tmp/cache/;
 INFO [fd9ff012] Finished in 0.178 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [4090c091] Running /usr/bin/env chmod 777 -R /var/fruby/shared/tmp/cache/; on somedomain.com
DEBUG [4090c091] Command: chmod 777 -R /var/fruby/shared/tmp/cache/;
 INFO [4090c091] Finished in 0.180 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 WARN [SKIPPING] No Matching Host for /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/fruby/releases/20140213100546'" 1>&2; false; fi
 WARN [SKIPPING] No Matching Host for bundle exec rake db:migrate
 INFO [a2e6371c] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /var/fruby/current on somedomain.com
DEBUG [a2e6371c] Command: /usr/bin/env rm -rf /var/fruby/current
 INFO [a2e6371c] Finished in 0.102 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [8081e6a1] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546 /var/fruby/current on somedomain.com
DEBUG [8081e6a1] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/fruby/releases/20140213100546 /var/fruby/current
 INFO [8081e6a1] Finished in 0.102 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [d14a199e] Running /usr/bin/env ls -x /var/fruby/releases on somedomain.com
DEBUG [d14a199e] Command: /usr/bin/env ls -x /var/fruby/releases
DEBUG [d14a199e]    20140213100546
DEBUG [d14a199e] Finished in 0.103 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [c681d69e] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/fruby/releases; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/fruby/releases'" 1>&2; false; fi on somedomain.com
DEBUG [c681d69e] Command: if test ! -d /var/fruby/releases; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/fruby/releases'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [c681d69e] Finished in 0.099 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [1e2e4a2e] Running /usr/bin/env echo "Branch master (at 13a3d23) deployed as release 20140213100546 by vitali; " >> /var/fruby/revisions.log on somedomain.com
DEBUG [1e2e4a2e] Command: echo "Branch master (at 13a3d23) deployed as release 20140213100546 by vitali; " >> /var/fruby/revisions.log
 INFO [1e2e4a2e] Finished in 0.099 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

And if it is of any help, Nginx passenger server block

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  somedomain.com;

    charset utf-8;
    root /var/fruby/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what command did you use  for deploying?

Comment: I can't find any restarting info in your capistrano messages. please run "cap deploy:restart" and test again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem just went away, perhaps server restarting did work, although I SWEAR that I had restarted server before and it didn't work before.